# Enjoyable or enjoyous

Tags: sentence-construction

I've got one sentence and I am not sure about correct form of enjoy. Here is it:

One of my most enjoyable hobbies is playing a musical 
instrument.

Should there be enjoyable or enjoyous? If enjoyous then could you provide an explanation? 
Thanks for answers!

Comment: If you look up "enjoyous" in a dictionary, you won't find it, because it's not a word.

Comment: *Enjoyous* does not seem to be in a dictionary... [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=enjoyous) or [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suggestions/enjoyous).  I could only find it in the [Urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=enjoyous) which means it's probably street or internet slang to be used with great care.

Answer (score 2):

The -ous suffix is used to convert a noun into an adjective.

> joy -> joyous
>   fame -> famous

enjoy is a verb, so you can't attach the -ous suffix to it.

The -able suffix converts a verb to an adjective:

> read -> readable
>   enjoy -> enjoyable

For more information about suffixes than you are ever likely to need, check out [this link](https://www.learnthat.org/pages/view/suffix.html).

Finally, before you use a new suffix-word, check it in a dictionary. In this case, you would have quickly found out that enjoyable is present and enjoyous is not.

Comment: Also Joyful. A bit different from enjoyable and joyous but close.